How can one be compensated for loss caused negligently by someone who dies in the process?
Consider the circumstance where an at-fault driver negligently collides with an innocent driver, but the at-fault driver dies.
Perhaps there is even evidence that the at-fault driver committed a crime in the process.
How can the victim be compensated, given that the at-fault driver is dead? Can the dead, at-fault driver still be charged? Can they still be sued?

united-states
Dead people can't be charged with crimes.
The estates of dead people can be sued for personal injuries that they caused during their life. The executor of the estate defends the lawsuit. If no estate is opened, the injured person can directly sue the insurance company for the deceased person in most jurisdictions.
Lawyers in the U.S. are generally willing to take cases of people injured in these situations on a contingency basis if the deceased person either has insurance or has significant assets.

Not really directly related to the question, but the question’s scenario and your wording made me think: can the estates of a dead person be sued for personal injuries they caused after their death? For example, if the driver had actually OD’ed on drugs and died while behind the wheel, hitting and injuring another driver after death occurred (and this could be proven forensically), would it still be possible to sue the estate for injuries?

They caused the injury by the actions they took before dying (driving while intoxicated), and so they (or their estate) is still liable. I don't think it's relevant when the injury actually occurred.

@JanusBahsJacquet: If you'll allow the loose analogy, the distinction whether I thrust the knife in you, or I throw it and it happens to land in you (the same way that the car I lose control over by ODing happens to hit you), is only relevant to establish my intent; not your personal injury or my complicity. The specific crime may change but the consequence (and complicity) remains the same. Your scenario fits vehicular manslaughter to a tee. Driving under the influence, enough to OD on, is most definitely criminal negligence.

@JanusBahsJacquet: The only purpose of establishing intent is to distinguish the severity of the crime (homicide vs manslaughter). As per the answer, the crime itself is irrelevant since dead people can't be charged with them anymore, so the distinction is moot for the purpose of OP's question of seeking reparations for injuries suffered due to another person's complicity in causing them.

@Flater In a civil case are punitive damages dependent on the defendant's state of mind? Are they moot when suing an estate?

@Barmar A civil case for punitive damages does depend upon the defendant's state of mind (as do many kinds of lawsuits) and can be brought against an estate. In general, intent is frequently relevant in lawsuits against estates. The distinction is between criminal prosecutions, which can't be brought against the dead, and civil lawsuits (which usually, but not always can be brought against the dead), not between offenses with and without intent. This is because the default remedy in a criminal case (incarceration) is irrelevant when a defendant is dead, and out of a larger simplifying policy.

Thanks. I was thinking of punitive damages as a way of saying "don't do that again" to the defendant, which makes no sense when the defendant is dead. But it can also be seen as a deterrant to others considering taking similar action in the future.

If the driver was a car driver with third-party liability insurance, I suppose that insurance still has to pay even if the driver died. Certainly if the driver dies after the accident. Also if he dies just before the accident? Say suicide using a gun, leaving their car in an extremely dangerous place?

@gnasher729 Death doesn't usually terminate a third-party liability insurance policy. The policy should still cover the accident even if the driver dies shortly before the accident. It is still the driver's actions (committing suicide) that contribute to the accident. Usually the vehicle is insured with a condition that it not be driven by certain excluded persons (like car thieves, but not excluding guests or no one at all driving such as when the brakes aren't on and it crashes).

@Barmar Punitive damages are a punishment on the offender and therefore relate to the act of committing a crime. So yes, intent matters to quantify the transgression made by the offender. But this is irrelevant for OP's question (and Janus' question) as the offender committing said crime has died, and you can't punish a dead person. Damages relating to injury don't hinge on the intent of the offender, only that they caused it. It might change who pays for it (e.g. if the offender was truly innocent in intent, it might be an insurance payout), but that's not on the victim to sort out.

@Flater "Punitive damages are a punishment on the offender and therefore relate to the act of committing a crime." This statement is incorrect. Punitive damages require an intentional act, but don't require that you committed a crime and can be recovered even if you didn't commit a crime or can't be prosecuted for committing a crime.

@ohwilleke I accept the distinction and admit I didn't refine my explanation because at the end of the day it's irrelevant for the question at hand since we're dealing with a dead offender in this hypothetical.

@Flater Just to be clear, a decedent's estate can be sued for punitive damages in the same circumstances when the decedent could be sued for them while alive, in most jurisdictions.

australia
The lifetime care needs of anyone injured in a motor vehicle accident are covered by the state or territory compulsory third-party personal injury policy, commonly called a green slip, because they’re green.
This is not insurance but rather a state-run no-fault compensation scheme.

In New Zealand, one doesn't even need the equivalent of a "green slip." Harms caused by accidental personal injuries are just universally covered by government benefits. It is basically a universal no-fault insurance plan for everyone, not just car accidents, and dramatically reduces the need for insurance.

canada
Ontario's Trustee Act allows for an action to be brought against the estate. See s. 38(2):

Except in cases of libel and slander, if a deceased person committed or is by law liable for a wrong to another in respect of his or her person or to another person’s property, the person wronged may maintain an action against the executor or administrator of the person who committed or is by law liable for the wrong

Other provinces are similar.

In situations like this, the at-fault driver's passing doesn't prevent a victim from pursuing compensation. Generally, the claim can proceed through the at-fault driver's insurance policy, which is meant to cover damages caused by their negligence. If the insurance limits are insufficient, you may be able to file a claim against the deceased's estate. Criminal charges wouldnt apply since the person has passed, but civil actions can still move forward to recover damages.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
